# Issues with using ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I am facing some issues with using 'ggplot' function. I have the data table (Crop_cond) as shown in the image. I am using the following code to obtain a bar plot as shown in the image below.

I was able to obtain the graph but I want to obtain the plot far below here. I want to flip the colors. Any suggestions.

My plot:
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks to me that you need `stat="identity"` to tell `geom_bar` that you are directly use the value instead of doing counting.

```
ggplot(Crop_cond, aes(x = END_CODE, y = VALUE)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill = CONDITION),stat = "identity",position="fill")
```

Comment: Or just use `geom_col() ` which is a wrapper for `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`

Comment: @Zang: Thanks it worked. But, I want to flip the colors now. please see the graphs above. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Jake: Thanks for your comment.